# React- leaflet how can I make variable in class that will change depending on object

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

I want to load icons dynamically, depending on type of object but this.skill returns undefined, I want to make it so I can have multiple different icons on map. I want skill variable to give values like 1, 2 ,3 but it returns undefined.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  
    this.state = {
      skill:adsArray.id,
    };
  }
  states = {
    center:{
      lat: 52.006376,
      lng: 19.025167,
    },
    zoom: 6.8
  }
 
  
 Icon =new L.icon({
    iconUrl: `/icons/`+this.skill+`.svg`,
   iconSize: new L.Point(60, 75),
   className: 'leaflet-div-icon'
  });
```

I try to import id from AdsArray - it is a .js file

```
import {adsArray} from '../data/arrays'
```

adsArray in arrays.js looks like this

```
export const adsArray = [
    {id:1, title:"Web", localization:2
```

and many more records, I only want to take ID from adsArray

Edit: I tried to do this like that trying to map AdsArray, but still

```
this.skill returns undefined
class Map extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  
    this.state = {
      skills:adsArray.map(skill =>(skill.id)),
    };
  }
  states = {
    center:{
      lat: 52.006376,
      lng: 19.025167,
    },
    zoom: 6.8
  }
 
  
 Icon =new L.icon({
    iconUrl: require(`../data/icons/`+this.skills+`.svg`).default,
   iconSize: new L.Point(60, 75),
   className: 'leaflet-div-icon'
  });
```

Comment: `this.skills` should be `this state.skills`. Moreover you should access a specific ID to L.icon's iconUrl not the entire array.

Comment: When I write `this state.skills`, I get an error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'skill')`. And I don't want the skill variable to be an array, I want it to be a single integer which changes depending on object.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer, I just had to do it like that - it s inside render function of class

```
 render(){
    return (
      <MapContainer className="map" center={this.states.center} zoom={this.states.zoom}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
         {adsArray.map(job => (
           this.skill=job.id,
        <Marker
          icon={L.icon({
            iconUrl: require(`../data/icons/`+this.skill+`.svg`).default,
            iconSize: new L.Point(60, 75),
          })}
           >
            </Marker>
      ))}
      </MapContainer>
    );
  }
}
```